# Dynamic allocation of struct using C

Tags: c

I'm trying to allocate an array of struct. When I try to initialize a value and print the value within the function, everything works fine. When I go and print the same value in main, my program crashes.

```
void getHeader(FILE* fpFile, HEADER *pHead)
{
   //  Local Declaration
   int worker, salesWeek, i;
   PERSON *list;

   //  Statement
   fscanf(fpFile, "%d %d", &worker, &salesWeek);
   list = aloPerson(worker);
   HEADER header = {worker, salesWeek, list};
   pHead = &header;

   return;
}// getHeader


PERSON* aloPerson(int worker)
{
   //  Local Declaration
   PERSON *list;

   //  Statement
   list =(PERSON*)calloc(worker, sizeof(PERSON));
   if(list == NULL)
   {
      MEM_ERROR, exit(103);
   }

   return list;
}// aloPerson
```

This is my struct.

```
typedef struct
{
int worker;
int weeks;
PERSON *pAry;
}HEADER;
```

This is main:

```
int main ( void )
{
//  Local Declaration
FILE* fpFile;
char  nameIn[25];
char *endPro = "end";
HEADER *pHead;

//  Statement
printf("Please select file to to open.\nsales or sales_2: ");
scanf("%s", nameIn);
FLUSH;

do
{
    valiFile(nameIn);
    fpFile = openFile(nameIn);
    getHeader(fpFile, pHead);
    readFile(fpFile, pHead);

    repeat(nameIn);
}
while(strcmp(nameIn, endPro) != 0);


return 0;
```

Comment: Because you're passing back a pointer to a locally stack allocated structure. You need to also dynamically allocate header.

Comment: getHeader amounts to a memory leak and some console IO in its current state. Probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Nick check that again, he's not even passing *that* back.

Comment: Ah yes, he's just setting the local copy of the pointer to his stack allocated object.

Comment: Exactly, which ironically, is fine (pointless, but fine none-the-less; at least it doesn't make it out of scope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to change this line of code:

```
HEADER header = {worker, salesWeek, list};
pHead = &header;
```

to be:

```
HEADER header = {worker, salesWeek, list};
*pHead = header;
```

also make sure pHead is not null otherwise return error null param. If you want to go dynamic then allocate header variable using calloc then you can use your old code then.

make sure in your main function that this line

```
HEADER *pHead;
```

is changed to

```
HEADER *pHead = (HEADER*)calloc(1, sizeof(HEADER));
```

also do not forget to free it.

Comment: +1 If `pHead` actually refers to  an allocated (either via scope or dynamic) HEADER structure, this is indeed correct. If it is just a naked pointer, the OP still has work to do. We don't really know as we can't see the caller side, but assuming it *is* a proper structure address, this works. The OP's comment "I'm trying to allocate an array of struct" suggests it *may* be half the story.

Comment: I just tried the above snippet and my program still crashes. Maybe it's something that I'm doing wrong in main. I'm going to include my main up top. Sorry, I'm new to structures and it's killing me.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez - Thanks, I fixed my code and now it's working fine. If it's not too much to ask for, can you please explain to me the logic behind why I needed to allocate memory for *pHead for it to work?

Comment: every pointer you pass to another function can be pointing to allocated memory or point to null/garbage. passing null pointer then trying to deference it with * would cause a crash (access violation). So each pointer must point to allocated memory before using it. in your case the main function declared a pointer and it is null then you tried to use it in another function which of course caused a crash.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez - Alright, that makes perfect senses. Thanks for taking the time to explain to me what I was doing wrong. I appreciate it.